# git diff shows the changes, git diff HEAD file doesn't

Tags: git

I edited a file inside my repo, now:

```
git status
```

says:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update w
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to

        modified:   myfile.txt
```

So `myfile.txt` is changed but i haven't done the `git add` so it is not staged.

Now if i do

```
git diff
```

I can see exactly what I changed since the last commit, but if i do:

```
git diff HEAD myfile.txt
```

nothing appears. So why git `diff HEAD` is different from `git diff` ?

### Solved

I mistyped the right case for myfile, the file itself is `myFile.txt` (note the big F). Now if id do `git diff HEAD myFile.txt` I get all the diff

Comment: What version of Git? I cannot reproduce with 1.9.5

Comment: I don't think, this is a valid question.

Comment: my error, mistyped the filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may refere following image. I don't think, you have that behaviour

[image]

For more details, check [here](http://365git.tumblr.com/post/3464927214/getting-a-diff-between-the-working-tree-and-other)

Comment: you should comment that image instead of copy/pasting from somewhere else

Comment: i mistyped the filename